# Execute the result of grep as a command

Tags: linux, command, tcsh

I grep a command from a file and I would like to pipe and execute them? Anyone has an idea?

```
cat README | grep source
```

gives `source myEnv.sh`

Comment: Learn a little about Useless use of `cat`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could surround the command with backticks:

```
$ `cat README | grep source`
```